# Query null values

Tags: sql, coldfusion, null, cfml, cfquery

I have the column `deletedTime` in my instances table.
Now I want to check in ColdFusion if the value is null.
There is only one record to be printed out with the query.
`IsNull(test)` is returning the correct value,
but `IsNull(searchForDeletedInstances.deletedTime)` returns `false` but the value is in the datatable null..

```
<cfquery datasource="hostmanager" name="searchForDeletedInstances">
SELECT deletedTime
FROM instances
WHERE instanceId = <cfqueryparam value="#instanceId#" 
cfsqltype="CF_SQL_NVARCHAR">
</cfquery>

<cfloop query="searchForDeletedInstances">
    <cfset test= #deletedTime#>
</cfloop>

<cfreturn IsNull(test)>
<cfreturn IsNull(searchForDeletedInstances.deletedTime)>
```

Comment: This could be handled in the cfquery tag using a WHERE clause that specifically looks for "AND deletedTime IS NULL".  Then you could use searchForDeletedInstances.recordCount to determine if a NULL value exists.  CF Versions before CF 2018 use empty strings to represent NULL values.  CF 2018 can reference NULL values but it has to be enabled per admin or application.

Comment: @ScottJibben Your comment is the answer to the question. Post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Null values from a query come back as empty strings. Test for IsDate() instead. You can always use cfdump to show the contents of your query so you can see the data and data types returned.

Comment: Thank you, works fine with the IsDate function. But sadly not with IsNull..

Answer (score 3):

I would do the test in the query.

```
<cfquery datasource="hostmanager" name="searchForDeletedInstances">
SELECT deletedTime
FROM instances
WHERE instanceId = <cfqueryparam value="#instanceId#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_NVARCHAR">
AND deletedTime IS NULL
</cfquery>

<cfreturn BooleanFormat(searchForDeletedInstances.recordcount)>
```

Answer (score 3):

ColdFusion 2018 does allow for NULL values but the server/site has to be configured to use it.  This may break a lot of older code.
ColdFusion before 2018 will use an empty string for NULL values.

I would change the query to only look for NULL deletedTime records.  Then use the searchForDeletedInstances.recordCount value to determine if a NULL record was found.  The code would look something like this:

```
<cfquery datasource="hostmanager" name="searchForDeletedInstances">
SELECT deletedTime
FROM instances
WHERE instanceId = <cfqueryparam value="#instanceId#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_NVARCHAR">
AND deletedTime IS NULL
</cfquery>

<cfset nullRecord = searchForDeletedInstances.recordCount ? true : false>

<cfreturn nullRecord>
```

Comment: Good stuff. FWIW, if the function return type is boolean, you could also just return recordCount which will be implicitly converted.

Comment: @Ageax Not true for all versions of CF. The `returnType` is only used for validation, so returning `1` would pass boolean validation, but the function would still return `1`. However, you could just return `(searchForDeletedInstances.recordCount gt 0)` here, since that would be a boolean expression. No ternary or `booleanFormat()` required.

Comment: Testing it in the query would be a solution if i only need the deletedTime tested. With the query i've got, i can test if the instanceId exists. With the solution you provided i can only check if the instanceId exists and has an empty deletedTime.

Comment: @Ageax, yes in my C/C++ coding I would have just used recordCount.  The problem is that some legacy code will specifically look for true/false.  CF allows for some of the weirdest stuff like <cfif someBooleanVar EQ "true">.  My C/C++ brain says that is a STRING.  CF, can evaluate that as a boolean.  That's why I usually force in a true/false value using a ternary expression.

Comment: Now i activated the null support. The IsNull function returns every time false.. also when there is clearly a NULL in deletedTime. For my purposes the IsDate function seems do to its job correctly so i now use this.

Comment: @dewey, sorry to hear that the null support isn't working for you.  It sounded like a good new feature but I have so much legacy code that I'm not sure I'd be able to use it unless a site is new.

Comment: @ScottJibben - True (no pun intended ;-) .. and I'm actually wrong about the returnType. I forgot that it only *tests* if a value can be cast as a particular type like boolean, but doesn't actually do the conversion. Most of the time it makes no difference, but even with non-legacy code I vaguely remember a weird case where it does, so yeah probably better to go with a ternary expression.

Comment: *can only check if the instanceId exists and has an empty deletedTime* @dewey - Technically you could check both by using a CASE statement in the SELECT to return a BIT flag indicating whether or not the value is null. Then both the recordCount and flag could be used in your logic. Though I'm curious why that makes a difference since the function only returns true/false?